# Need to take the 4th word of a line and copy it to the start of the line (sed awk)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with 5 million lines:

```
xx ss ss "abcde"
```

I need to take `"abcde"` and copy it to the start of each line:

```
"abcde" xx ss ss "abcde"
```

The string `"abcde"` changes in each line so, it's not a specific word but it's always the 4th word in each line.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative awk :

```
awk '{print $4,$0}' file
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file7
abc def ghi nop
klm one two three
four five six nine

$ awk '{print $4,$0}' file7
nop abc def ghi nop
three klm one two three
nine four five six nine
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, assuming the columns are separated by a number of spaces and there could be additional comlumns:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]* *\)\{3\}\([^ ]*\)/\2 &/'
```

The pattern matches three repeated columns, identified as non-spaces followed by spaces, followed by another column, referenced as `\2` in the replacement string. The `&` puts the whole match in the replacement, so the fourth column is inserted before the whole remains of the line.

Note that this will work with more than four columns, but will fail if there is no fourth column.

Same when extended regex are available (FreeBSD or GNU `sed`):

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]* *){3}([^ ]*)/\2 &/'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better answers here, but here's a for in loop that works also:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat file); do var=$(echo $i | awk '{print $4}')  ; sed -i "s/.*$var/$var &/g" file ;done
```

Comment: `$(cat file)` when `file` has "5 million lines"? :)

Comment: Fair point. unnecessarily over complicating this... could easily be done like `awk '{print $4,$1,$2,$3,$4}' file` and redirect into a new file if needs be

Answer (score 0):

We place the 4th field `$F[3]` alongwith the list separtor `$"` (which defaults to `space`) at the beginning of the record/line. The `-p` option will `autoprint` the record.

```
perl -pale 's/^/$F[3]$"/' yourfile
```

With the sed command we save a copy of the original and fence the 4th field. Then we take away the leading portion. And reinstate the original by appending to the pattern space, which now holds the 4th field.

```
sed -e '
   /\n/!h
   //!s/\S\+/\n&\n/4
   /\n.*\n/D
   s/\n.*//;G;s/\n/ /
' yourfile
```